# How to string format a whole list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list/array and I want to string format it. For example,

```
 a = [1, 2, 3] and output that I want should be 010203
```

I tried with `b = "%.2d %(a)"`, however, it gives me an error `TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not list`. Of course, I can understand this error, but, I don't know the other way.

The code should be generic, I mean, when my list is like `a = [10, 11, 12, 13]`, then, it should print the output like `10111213`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> "".join("%.2d" % i for i in a)
'010203'
>>> a = [10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> "".join("%.2d" % i for i in a)
'10111213'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024

Comment: @alecxe, thanks a lot. Actually, I also got the answer by myself. Thanks anyway.